# (iOS) Way of viewing log messages directly on an iOS device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, logging, nslog

As nice as debuggers have gotten these days, sometimes the best way of finding out what is going on in an app is still ye olde `NSLog`.  Doing this is easy when you're tethered to your computer; Xcode helpfully pops up the Log Viewer panel and there you go.  Not so easy to do when you're away from your desk, as you sometimes have to be when testing an app (for example, when you are testing CoreLocation functionality).  Sure you can pop open Xcode and check the Console section of the Device Organizer as soon as you get back from a testing run, but then you have to wait, and by the time you can get back to view the logs you forgot what was going wrong with your app; also odds are that by the time you are able to do this, the log messages you are looking for have scrolled off into oblivion.

Is there any way of checking the console logs on the device itself?  I'm guessing the answer is "no, unless you jailbreak" (IIRC there are at least one or two terminal apps in jailbreak-land that I could use to do this sort of thing).  Unfortunately jailbreaking is not an option for me.

Alternatively, is there some sort of Objective-C framework or library or whatnot that handles log collection and on-device displaying?  Ideally this would come in the form of a drop-in replacement for `NSLog`, whereby I could simply do a search-and-replace and change all occurrences of `NSLog` to `SomeFancyPantsLoggingTool` or whatever and be done with it.

A good example of the kind of functionality I am looking for can be found in the podcast client [Downcast](http://www.downcastapp.com).  If you tap the "More" tab, then tap on the version number string at the bottom of the screen, a new view slides up that contains a scrollable view of accumulated log messages.  It even has an easy way of mailing said logs to a support e-mail address.

Comment: Thou shalt no replace ye olde `NSLog()`. Thou shalt connect to the syslog instead. `man syslog` and `man syslogd` are your friends, also try to connect to `lockdownd` and get the syslog out of that (it's a private API though, so `#ifdef` it out before submitting to the AppStore.)

Comment: I generally use my own logger. I have a set of defines that work with NSLog and my own parameters. Since I want to have my own logs in separate files (per day) I just redirect all logs to a newly created file by calling "freopen" with "stderr" freopen([pathToFile UTF8String], "a", stderr). I can then send those logs to myself when the user has a problem and clicks my "contact support" button.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [LibComponentLogging](http://0xc0.de/LibComponentLogging) which you can configure to output logging at different levels and to different destinations.

Answer (score 0):

There is a file for the SysLog. You can simply open it and read from it. The file is at /var/log/syslog. If the file does not exist there are instructions on how to set it up [here](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/System_Log).